# Rails Mass Assignment--how to go about this

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a receiver_id and sender_id that I am getting through hidden form fields. These attributes are attr_accessible, so they are mass assignable. However, I don't want it to be subject to mass assignment. How would I go about this without having to resort to hidden form fields and making the receiver and sender id attr_accessible?

controller

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @first_name = @user.first_name
    @last_name = @user.last_name
    @wallpost = WallPost.new(params[:wall_post])
    @showwallposts = @user.received_wallposts
end

def create
    @wallpost = WallPost.create(params[:wall_post])
end
```

models

```
class WallPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :receiver_id, :sender_id
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :sent_wallposts, :class_name => 'WallPost', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'  
has_many :received_wallposts, :class_name =>'WallPost', :foreign_key => 'receiver_id'
```

in the view

```
    <%= form_for(@wallpost, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :receiver_id, :value => @user.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id %>    
      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'inputbox' %>
      <%= f.submit 'Post', class: 'right btn' %>    
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Without knowing more about what your models are and what `receiver_id` and `sender_id` are for, it's very hard to say why you should or should not use mass assignment or the best way to do what you want to do. Based on the names, I'm guessing your concern is security and there is a rule like only the current user can be the `sender_id`. If this is the case the solution is to not put `sender_id` in the form but just set it from current user in the controller. More information is required to give a full useful answer.

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your comment. I'm going to edit my post to show more information.

Comment: To add to my last comment, I don't want it so a user could mass assign the receiver_id in the form and the sender_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is similar to what I imagined your set up might be.

So you want `sender_id` to be the the id of the current user.

So you should have:

```
def create
  @wallpost = current_user.sent_wallposts.create(params[:wall_post])
end
```

It doesn't matter then that `receiver_id` is mass_assigned as there is no problem assigning the receiver.

It seems you are also interested in restricting the receiver_id. You can do that as well:

```
def create
  receiver_id = params[:wall_post].delete(:receiver_id)
  @wallpost = current_user.sent_wallposts.build(params[:wall_post])
  @wallpost.receiver_id = receiver_id
  @wallpost.save
end
```

However, that doesn't really change the situation at all since there is no different between that and mass assigning the value. The only reason you would want to avoid mass assignment of that value is if there is some additional logic that you want to put in place around whether a user can send to another user. In which case it would be something like this:

```
def create
  receiver_id = params[:wall_post].delete(:receiver_id)
  if current_user.can_send_to(receiver_id)
    @wallpost = current_user.sent_wallposts.build(params[:wall_post])
    @wallpost.receiver_id = receiver_id
    @wallpost.save
  end
end
```

You of course would need to create some method that can determine if the user can send to that receiver. And at this point your action is getting very complex and I would refactor this whole thing to take this out of your controller action.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That's what I figured. I just wanted to figure out how I could stop the receiver from being mass assigned. I suppose it's not possible. Thanks again.

Comment: It possible, I just didn't see why you would want to restrict it based on information given. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex. You are right. It's not necessary to restrict it. But I was curious as to how I could in case I wanted to. I just think it's kind of weird allowing the user to technically be able to post on to a person's wall from another person's wall by modifying the receiver_id. I'm very new to rails and I haven't really read a book on it. Just reading tutorials online. I learned a lot from your post.